# Integrating refinerycms into an existing rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, refinerycms

I tried incorporating refinerycms in my application following this [documentation](http://www.refinerycms.com/guides/with-an-existing-rails-app). After adding the gem to the gemfile and running bundler, I'm getting some errors when I run rails g refinery:cms --fresh-installation or when I try to run any rails or rake command.

Here's my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported      runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read     more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more:   https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

#refinerycms
gem 'refinerycms'

group :development, :test do
# Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a  debugger console
 gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
 # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
 gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

 # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in   the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
 gem 'spring'
 end

 group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
 end

 ruby "2.2.0"
```

and the stack trace

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/speakingurl-rails-1.1.5/lib/speakingurl-rails.rb:8:in `block in <class:Railtie>': undefined method `prepend_path' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
from /Users/Jesmine/workspace/proj/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:142:in `require_application_and_environment!'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:67:in `console'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `speakingurl-rails` gem not yet supports Sprockets 3.0.
I fixed this by locking `gem 'sprockets-rails', '~> 2.3.3'` in Gemfile.

Here is pull requests for [RefineryCMS](https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms/pull/3080) and and [speakingurl](https://github.com/pid/speakingurl/pull/70).